# SSIS Add a new column with a value

Tags: ssis, merge

I want to add a column (with just a value) to my main table using SSIS (see example below). 
How do you do? 
Merge join? Merge? Union all? Derived column? I tried all ways but I couldn't do it.

[image: Example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If every row is getting the same value or there is a static translation (Age between 18 and 68 = City of LA; otherwise, City of New Orleans) then a Derived Column is your best bet.

If there are lots of values or they are subject to change, then I'd look at using a Lookup Task.

A Merge Task is going to have a requirement of sorted data and it's a harder fit for what you're trying to do.

Comment: How do you use the derived column with SQL though?  I assume he wants to add data to the column 'City' by using a query like "Select Name From Cities Where Name = 'Los Angeles'".